# clang-format: Lambda on single line doesn't work

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm using clang-format and I want my lambda's to be on a single line.
I set `AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All`, but when I format this:

```cpp
auto l = [] (auto x) { return 2 * x; };
```

I get this:

```cpp
auto l = [] (auto x)
{ return 2 * x; };
```

which of course looks weird and is not the expected behavior.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

My complete `.clang-format` looks like this:

```
---
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands: AlignAfterOperator
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: "true"
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All #NonAssignment
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakStringLiterals: false
ColumnLimit: 0
CommentPragmas:  '^[^ ]'
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
Language: Cpp
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2
NamespaceIndentation: Inner
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments: false
SortIncludes: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: NonEmptyParentheses
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: "c++20"
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
---
AlignTrailingComments: true
BasedOnStyle: Chromium
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
ColumnLimit: 0
IndentWidth: 4
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
Language: ObjC
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PointerAlignment: Left
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
```

Comment: I highly recommend alphabetizing your `.clang-format` file. I was about give the glib answer that you didn't have the option in your file.

Comment: @sweenish You're right, I updated the post.

Comment: As a test, does it work if you change `BreakBeforeBraces: Allman` to `Attach`? If yes, you might need to either set a custom rule for `BraceWrapping` or play with the priorities.

Comment: @sweenish That did it! Thank you! I set ```BreakBeforeBraces: Custom``` and added custom ```BraceWrapping```.